# Как отправить файл через илайн кнопки в aiogram

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

Использую aiogram, возник следующий вопрос. Как можно по нажатию на Inline-кнопку отправить файл (docx, pdf, etc)? После выбора семестра отправляется выбор предмета, и не знаю как сделать отправку файла, после того, как был выбран предмет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Так же, как и не через инлайн кнопки https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument

Comment: @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == ['tests'])
async def send_file(message: types.Document):
   await message.reply_document(open("E:\\BOT\\_info\\навички.docx", 'rb'))

Вот пример кода, но при етом бот не отправляет файл, помогите правильно написать код